# jQuery load does not run

Tags: jquery, jquery-load

I have got the following code

```
 <script>
$( "#brand" ).change(function() {
   var values = $(this).serialize();
   console.log(values);
    $( "#model" ).load( "model.php?" + values);
});     
  </script>
```

The values are logged in the console. So the change function works and var values succesfully serializes the form fields.

The div id model exists but is not filled.

When I go to model.php?brand=123 myself the html output is correct

The load function however does not seem to do anything.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is your path correct?

Comment: it is in the same directory on a localhost without any htaccess or something

Comment: can you please add model.php code....

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan he's debugging in console and said the change function works as intended.

Comment: @MikeHometchko Good point. That'll teach me to skim read :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check response code first.

```
    function( response, status, xhr ) {
  if ( status == "error" ) {
    var msg = "Sorry but there was an error: ";
    $( "#error" ).html( msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText );
  }
});
```

add this code like $(element).load(url, function(){..});

Try this:

```
$( "#model" ).load( "model.php" ,values);
```

Comment: $( "#model" ).load( "model.php" ,values);

try this

Comment: thanks that did the trick :) accepting your answer in 5 minutes

Answer (score 4):

```
<script>
$( "#brand" ).change(function() {
   var values = $(this).serialize();
   console.log(values);

    $("#model").load("model.php", { brand:123});
     or
    $("#model").load("model.php", values);
});     
  </script>
```

hope this will work

Comment: Incorrect syntax in the URL parameters wouldn't cause the .load() to fail execution (at least in this sense)

Comment: please give full path in load then try